# Remove attribute content on model using Carrierwave and callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes, carrierwave

I'm trying to remove file attributes from the model when an uploaded file is remove (using a checkboxe).  The file is removed correctly, but not the attributes.  Can someone help me?  I don't want to move this piece of code inside the model.  I think it must reside inside the uploader.

```
# DocumentUploader.rb

# Hooks
before :cache, :update_file_attributes
after :remove, :remove_file_attributes

private

def update_file_attributes(file)
  model.file_name = file.original_filename
  model.file_size = file.size
  model.mime_type = file.content_type
end

def remove_file_attributes
  %w(file_name file_size mime_type).each { |attr| model[attr] = "" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Came upon this problem myself just now. I got it to work in my app doing, analogously, something like this:

```
def remove_file_attributes
  model.file_name = ""
  model.file_size = ""
  model.mime_type = ""

  model.save
end
```

Guessing yours will work just fine too, but you just need to add 'model.save'.
Note: after doing this, the fields in my database are NULL, not an empty string (which is fine for me).